# Как правильно вывести результат обработки файла из функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, вывод

```
import json
from vkon.news import get_json


def get_text():
    with open('posts.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:  # открываем файл на чтение
        data = json.load(file)
        count = 1
        for i in data['response']['items']:
            if i['text']:
                print(str(count) + ' Сообщение:')
                print(i['text'] + '\n')
                count += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_json()
    get_text()
```

Как изменить данный код, чтобы он выводил результат не в консоль, а возвращал в другую программу?
    Даже если вместо Print присвоить результат переменным:

```
message = str(count) + ' Сообщение:'
text = i['text'] + '\n'
```

А в конце функции сделать `return message, text`, то возвращается лишь последний записанный результат, т. к. переменная постоянно перезаписывается.

P. S. Потом данная функция импортируется в другую программу. Там нужен построчный вывод всех записанных результатов, а не только последнего.

Answer (score 1):

"Продвинутый" вариант - меняем `print` на `yield`, и функция волшебным образом превращается в генератор:

```
def get_text():
    with open('posts.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:  # открываем файл на чтение
        data = json.load(file)
        count = 1
        for i in data['response']['items']:
            if i['text']:
                yield str(count) + ' Сообщение:\n' + i['text']
                count += 1
```

Последовательно вывести все результаты:

```
for message in get_text():
    print(message)
```

Вывести результаты в виде списка:

```
print(list(get_text()))
```

Более "новичковский" способ: накапливаем результат в списке, в конце возвращаем полный список через `return`:

```
def get_text():
    with open('posts.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        count = 1
        result = []
        for i in data['response']['items']:
            if i['text']:
                result.append(str(count) + ' Сообщение:\n' + i['text'])
                count += 1

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно возвращать отформатированный список:

```py
import json


def get_text():
    with open('posts.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

        res = []
        for i, item in enumerate(data['response']['items']):
            res.append(
                f"{i} Сообщение:\n"
                f"{item['text']}\n"
            )
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    res = get_text()
    print(*res, sep='\n')
```

stdout:

```html
0 Сообщение:
Hello, World!

1 Сообщение:
Spam!

2 Сообщение:
Eggs!
```